# Why is there a huge gap before in my WebPageTest after the HTML has been downloaded?

Tags: performance

I am trying to improve front-end performance of my website, and there is a 3.5 second lag before the user actually sees anything, and I'd like to improve this.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

And here is the actual test:
http://www.webpagetest.org/result/130301_JC_12CC/2/details/cached/

The user is seeing a blank screen for about 3.5 seconds before it's visually complete, which is pretty unacceptable in my opinion. Any pointers on how I could solve this?

Comment: I do not believe this can be answered with the information you've provided.  Have a link to the real site?  Have you tried using the profiler in firebug?  This is usually my first point of call.

Comment: There is a link to the page being tested if you visit the link that was given to webpagetest.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that particular chart has hidden the images that are downloading during that time period.  I tested the same page myself using the Firefox web browser with the Firebug extension.  A similar chart to what the website gives you is available under the "net" tab in Firebug.

As you can see, there are a lot more resources downloaded from your site and there are no significant gaps. [View full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ8CQ.png)

[image]